# Entity Framework is not identifying primary key defined in database table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-5

```
CREATE TABLE [Admin].[PlanManagers]
(
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(10000,1) CONSTRAINT PK_PLANMANAGERS Primary key NOT NULL,
    [AdminUserId] [bigint] 
         CONSTRAINT FK_ADMINUSER_PLANMANAGERS 
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Login].[AdminUsers]([Id])
            ON DELETE SET NULL NULL,
    [PlanName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [PlanIntro] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Active] [bit] Default(0) NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] Default(getutcdate()) NOT NULL,
    [Updated] [datetime] Default(getutcdate()) NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdatedBy] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
)
```

I have added an Entity Framework Data Model for this database table but Entity Framework doesn't recognize the primary key.

I have manually mentioned the `ID [Key]` using data annotations.

What is the most possible cause of the bug..

Comment: Did you try updating your model again ?

Comment: #Harvery I have  trying updating model using "Update Model from Database"

Comment: @TusharT. did you find what was the problem?